# Linux - parsing data, what language to use

Tags: linux, bash, parsing, awk

I am looking to parse data out of a 'column' based format. I am running into issues where I feel I am 'hacking' bash/awk commands to pull the strings and numbers. If the numbers/text come in different formats then the script might fail unexpectedly and I will have errors.

**Data:**

```
RSSI (dBm):    -86      Tx Power:    0
RSRP (dBm):    -114     TAC:         4r5t (12341)
RSRQ (dB):     -10      Cell ID:     efefwg (4261431)
SINR (dB):      2.2
```

**My method:**

Using bash and awk

```
#!/bin/bash

DATA_OUTPUT=$(get_data)

RSSI=$(echo "${DATA_OUTPUT}" | awk '$1 == "RSSI" {print $3}')
RSRP=$(echo "${DATA_OUTPUT}" | awk '$1 == "RSRP" {print $3}')
RSRQ=$(echo "${DATA_OUTPUT}" | awk '$1 == "RSRQ" {print $3}')
SINR=$(echo "${DATA_OUTPUT}" | awk '$1 == "SINR" {print $3}')
TX_POWER=$(echo "${DATA_OUTPUT}" | awk '$4 == "Tx" {print $6}')

echo "$SINR"
echo ">$SINR<"
```

However the output of the above comes out very strange.

```
2.2   # thats fine!
<2.2  # what??? expecting >4.6<
```

Little things like this make me question using awk and bash to parse the data. Should I use C++ or some other language? Or is there a better way of doing this?

Thank you

Comment: I cannot reproduce the issue. Also, what is your question exactly, printing `<$var>` or parsing data or both?

Comment: What languages are you familiar with? What environment do you work (what kind of data? Simple data as above, lots of data in databases, scientific data, etc). That can help answering your question better.

Comment: You may also want to ask your question at http://programmers.stackexchange.com/ , which seems a better suited site for such a broad question.

Comment: You should `echo $DATA_OUTPUT` to ensure it contains what you expect.

Comment: Also, please make sure your example is correct: `get_data` is not provided (I used `cat $1`), and your output should be 2.2, not 4.6 (see the input). As it currently, like JS above, I can't reproduce your results.

Comment: Sorry for delay trying many things... @JS i am trying to get the numbers into a variable to use. Evert I cna use anything that can run on debian system (C++98/bash/perl) not python. ooga it is correct. Also Evert, I am getting the variable correctly but sometimes it adds a return carriage.

Comment: awk is the standard UNIX tool for parsing/manipulating text files. Your posted code doesn't show any reason for additional bash constructs beyond calling awk once. You should definitely not be considering C++ or similar as that will require you writing the code for many details that awk does for you by default. Are your columns tab-separated? If not how do you know whether `Tx Power:` is one column or 2?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should be your starting point (the `match()` can be simplified or removed if your input data is tab-separated or fixed width fields):

```
$ cat file
RSSI (dBm):    -86      Tx Power:    0
RSRP (dBm):    -114     TAC:         4r5t (12341)
RSRQ (dB):     -10      Cell ID:     efefwg (4261431)
SINR (dB):      2.2
```

.

```
$ cat tst.awk
{
    tail = $0
    while ( match(tail,/[^:]+:[[:space:]]+[^[:space:]]+[[:space:]]*([^[:space:]]*$)?/) )
    {
        nvPair = substr(tail,RSTART,RLENGTH)
        sub(/ \([^)]+\):/,":",nvPair)           # remove (dB) or (dBm)
        sub(/:[[:space:]]+/,":",nvPair)         # remove spaces after :
        sub(/[[:space:]]+$/,"",nvPair)          # remove trailing spaces
        split(nvPair,tmp,/:/)
        name2value[tmp[1]] = tmp[2]             # name2value["RSSI"] = "-86"
        tail = substr(tail,RSTART+RLENGTH)
    }
}

END {
    for (name in name2value) {
        value = name2value[name]
        printf "%s=\"%s\"\n", name, value
    }
}
```

.

```
$ awk -f tst.awk file
Tx Power="0"
RSSI="-86"
TAC="4r5t (12341)"
Cell ID="efefwg (4261431)"
RSRP="-114"
RSRQ="-10"
SINR="2.2"
```

Hopefully it's clear that in the above script after the match() loop you can simply say things like `print name2value["Tx Power"]` to print the value of that key phrase.

If your data was created in DOS, run `dos2unix` or `tr -d '^M'` on it first, where `^M` means a literal control-M character.

Answer (score 0):

Your data contains DOS-style \r\n line endings. When you do this

```
echo ">$SINR<"
```

The actual output is actually

```
>4.6\r<
```

The carriage return sends the cursor back to the start of the line.

You can do this:

```
DATA_OUTPUT=$(get_data | sed 's/\r$//')
```

But instead of parsing the output over and over, I'd rewrite like this:

```
while read -ra fields; do
    case ${fields[0]} in
        RSSI) rssi=${fields[2]};;
        RSRP) rsrp=${fields[2]};;
        RSPQ) rspq=${fields[2]};;
        SINR) sinr=${fields[2]};;
    esac
    if [[ ${fields[3]} == "Tx" ]]; then tx_power=${fields[5]}; fi
done < <(get_data | sed 's/\r$//' )
```

Comment: Getting Syntax error: redirection unexpected. Also trying to understand so I can fix it to

Comment: This script uses bash specific features, so do not invoke it with `sh scriptname`

Comment: The `sed 's/\r$//'` command has to be invoked on every variable not just the data as a whole. So I'll change it to incorporate that. Thanks for the script.

Comment: The while loop reads from a [process substitution](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Process-Substitution) -- that basically means bash can read a pipeline as if it's a file.

Comment: I don't understand what you mean with your sed comment. You need to remove the carriage returns from the data, and you only need to do that once.

Comment: Doesnt seem to be working for me did you echo "${sinr}" echo ">${sinr}<". Still adds return

Comment: Try this: `get_data | od -c` and see where the carriage returns are.